# How to use MaltParser using python On windows

Tags: parsing, python-2.7, nltk

I am trying to use python nltk wrapper of MaltParser on my windows machine for dependency Parsing. I went through several help and posts here but unable to resolve my issue.
After downloading various version zip of MLT parser I am still unable to run it.
In eclipse I added maltparser-1.8.1.jar file as dependency and also tried adding malt.jar from earlier version but not working.

Here is my basic implementation

```
import nltk
parser2 =nltk.parse.malt.MaltParser()
txt="This is a test sentence"
parser2.train_from_file('engmalt.poly-1.7.mco')
parser2.raw_parse(text)
```

I am getting this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Mrinal\workspace\RSTParser\depParser.py", line 7, in <module>
    parser2 =nltk.parse.malt.MaltParser()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\malt.py", line 36, in __init__
    self.config_malt()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\parse\malt.py", line 88, in config_malt
    verbose=verbose)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 544, in find_binary
    binary_names, url, verbose))
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 538, in find_binary_iter
    url, verbose):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\nltk\internals.py", line 517, in find_file_iter
    raise LookupError('\n\n%s\n%s\n%s' % (div, msg, div))
LookupError: 

===========================================================================
NLTK was unable to find the malt.jar file!
Use software specific configuration paramaters or set the MALT_PARSER environment variable.

  Searched in:
    - .

  For more information, on malt.jar, see:
    <http://www.maltparser.org/>
===========================================================================
```

Please guide me as I am new to this. Thanks!
Also any idea on other parser which can be run easily for dependency parse on windows. I trying looking Stanford's core NLP but using it python is not the easiest.